# Remove admin domain in Chrome OS

Tags: linux, root, google-chrome-os, domain-security

I would like to ask a question about resetting a Chromebook that I recently got after my graduation a week ago.

I followed the steps to go to Developer Mode and wipe the Chromebook, yet it asks me to log in with the domain name of our school.

How can I remove the admin domain in Chrome OS that does not require me rewriting the boot order to Chromium OS.

Comment: You should ask your school. If it wasn't meant to be like this then they should be able to remove it from the device. That's the best way and other students who have received devices should be informed as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They have likely installed what is known as a [custom build](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/deploy-windows-mdt/create-a-windows-10-reference-image) of the OS on the chromebook. You will need to completely reinstall the operating system from scratch, not just wipe it, in order to remove their build.

Comment: Sorry, but I think the OP is asking about Chrome OS, how does this related to Windows 10?